# How do I add a horizontal submenu?

Tags: html, css, menu

I would like to have a dropdown sub- menu in the same style, I know it's simple but I'm still new to making websites and I can't figure it out by myself.

here's the top part of my HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Startpagina</title>
    <LINK href="../CSS/stylesheet.css" rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
<div class="schikking">
    <img src="../Images/bibram.png" alt="Logo van de bib" height="90" width="170">
    <!-- navigatie -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./index.html"><span class ="s2">Startpagina</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="./aanwinsten.html">Aanwinsten</a></li>
                <li><a href="./catalogus.html">Catalogus</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">New Posts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="./uitlening.html">Uitlening</a></li>
                <li><a href="./reservatie.html">Reservatie</a></li>
                <li><a href="./suggestie.html">Suggestie</a></li>
                <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

and a big part of my CSS file:

```
.schikking {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    max-width: 1010px;
}

.content {
    background-color: red;
    background-color: rgba(147, 4, 0, 0.84);
    border: 1px solid black;
}

nav li
{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 8px;

}
nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px;

}
nav ul{
    background-color: rgba(126, 4, 0, 0.79);
    border: 1px solid black;


}
nav ul li{
    display: inline;

}
nav ul li a{
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightgray;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #999999;

}

nav ul ul{display: none; position: relative;}
nav li ul li{float:none;display: inline-block; }
nav ul li:hover ul  {display: inline-block;}
```

heres a picture of how it looks atm:

normal: http://gyazo.com/8f6553245b736feee8cc5ebf8d4a030c
while hovering over "catalogus": http://gyazo.com/662eee4bbbb2ea2318925be76b3722d2

Comment: Try this tutorial for a CSS only (no JavaScript) solution: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: You need to `position:absolute` the "sub-menu" in order to remove the it from the _normal flow_ of the main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nearly got it. I have only made some minor changes to the CSS to make it work.

`nav ul li { display: inline-block; height: 100%; }` instead of just `display: inline` is required so that the each `<li>` takes up all the height of the "menu" otherwise there is a small gap between the bottom of the `<li>` and the sub-menu which would cancel the `:hover` event since you are out of the `<li>`. `inline` elements do not have `height` (or `width`), so changed to `display: inline-block`.

The CSS at the end is where the other changes are. Your code is:

```
nav ul ul{display: none; position: relative;}
nav li ul li{float:none;display: inline-block; }
nav ul li:hover ul  {display: inline-block;}
```

The display code doesn't need to be anything more than

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

But to position the sub-menu outside of it's normal flow (which is currently appearing next to the parent menu item), you need to add an absolute position to the sub-menu `.

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you want a horizontal menu, that should be all the changes needed, since your rule `nav ul li { display: inline-block; }`will already apply to the sub-menu list-items. If you want a vertical menu, you need to reset the `display` back to the default `list-item` or `block` with:

```
nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Vxg4/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it yourself. I use this jquery plug-in and its great:

[Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)

Comment: This requires JavaScript and specifically the jQuery library, not sure that fits the OP's need.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with anything I'd reccomend you to google them first. Here's a generator (just choose the one you want and follow the instructions):
[Css drop down menu maker](http://cssmenumaker.com/css-drop-down-menu)

I would also reccomend you to actually learning the language and expanding your knowledge, as well as googling questions before posting them here.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="./index.html"><span class ="s2">Startpagina</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="./aanwinsten.html">Aanwinsten</a></li>
    <li><a href="./catalogus.html">Catalogus</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Posts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./uitlening.html">Uitlening</a></li>
    <li><a href="./reservatie.html">Reservatie</a></li>
    <li><a href="./suggestie.html">Suggestie</a></li>
    <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
nav {
 margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px; 
text-align: center;}
nav ul ul {
display: none;
padding-right: 8px;}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;}
nav ul {
background-color: red;
border: 1px solid black;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;}
nav ul:after {
content: ""; clear: both; display: block;}
nav ul li {
float: left;}
nav ul li:hover a {
color: #999999;}
nav ul li a {
display: block;
padding-left: 1em;
padding-right: 1em;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: lightgray;}
nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;}
nav ul ul li {
float: none;  position: relative;padding: 10px;}
nav ul ul li a {

color: #fff;}
nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;}
```

Comment: it works when I hover over Catalogus but when I go down the menu it goes away